# How to make web icon open with specific browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, website, icons, web

I have an icon on my desktop for a website called QUAKE LIVE and I use Google Chrome as my default browser. The website isn't compatible with Google Chrome, but it with Mozilla Firefox. Is there any way to edit the properties of the icon to open with Firefox instead of Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new shortcut that launches your browser with the URL as a parameter.

So a shortcut with a target like below would start superuser.com in Internet Explorer.

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://superuser.com/"
```